# Did Buddha comment on Hindu incarnations like Krishna Rama etc?

Tags: the-buddha, nirvana, enlightenment, hinduism

Just wondering, did the Shakyamuni Buddha say anything about Rama or Krishna especially, because he and only he was deemed to be fully awakened by Hindus. He was awakened (may not be fully) is kinda evident from his teachings from Bhagavata Geeta too.

Comment: Krishna is not mentioned in the Buddhist scriptures

Comment: Related: [Is Krishna a demon?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/47558/471)

Comment: Related: [Did the Buddha make any reference to Krishna and Gita?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14785/471)

Answer (score 1):

No.
Story of Krishna and Rama are fictitious stories.
In fact Rama was  partly mentioned as buddhas past life in jataka katha.

Even the concept of Ishvara(GOD) was not there. ´ekeshvarvad(theory of single GOD) and sarveshvarvad(theory of omnipresent GOD) was later development, in Hinduism as well as Mahayan buddhism.

So obviously the theory of their incarnation should have come  even later.

However initial notion of non-dualism ( brahman) was there even before buddha. The famous sage Uddalak,( or his son swetketu) was one of Buddhas teacher. So obviously the concept mentioned in Chandogya upnishad and  Brihadaranyak upnishad were prevailing in buddhas time too.
And what buddhas said is there nibbana is going beyond that stage of non-duality.

[Bhikkhu sujato says udaka ramaputta is rishi udalaks liniage.](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/a-ara-kalama-uddaka-ramaputta-what-tradition/6210/6)

Comment: Doesn't Ghata Jataka clearly mention Krishna?